# How to hide loading on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, jquery-mobile

[image]

You can see "Loading" underneath a footer. How do I get rid of it? It is shown on iPhone device too.

I think it is something to do with jQuery as local folder as

```
<script src="js/1.7_jquery.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I did not do anything on xcode to hide "Loading"? Please advise if I need to do anything on info.plist?

**UPDATE:** Look like it is not jQuery as Loading still appear on a live browser when viewing.

Comment: The location of where you get your jquery script has nothing to do with it.

Comment: **Stop using phonegap and switch to obj-c?** I'm using HTML5, CSS3 and JS for my designs. I know what obj-c is. How can I switch to obj-c from Phonegap? Would I be able to do this in Xcode?

Comment: I am saying using HTML and PhoneGap is bound to have problems. Using obj-c with a native executable should remove the problem

Comment: Irishgirl could you post the whole HTML? Thanks

Comment: `<script src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script><!-- Arrange in this order no2 -->
<script src="js/1.7_jquery.min.js"></script><!-- Arrange in this order no1 -->
<script src="js/phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script><!-- Arrange in this order no3 -->`

Comment: It is sorted by re-arranging the order from top to line two.
<script src="js/1.7_jquery.min.js"></script><!-- Arrange in this order no1 -->
"Loading" disappears.